Calculating sums of nested dictionaries into the dictionary
I'm writing a program that helps collate data from a few sources to perform analysis on.
I currently have a dictionary that looks like this:
output = {
            "main":
                {
                    "overall":
                        {
                            "overall":
                                {
                                    "total": {"q1": 0,"q2": 0,"q3": 0,"q4": 0},
                                    "Profit": {"q1": 0,"q2": 0,"q3": 0,"q4": 0},
                                    "Loss": {"q1": 0,"q2": 0,"q3": 0,"q4": 0},
                                },
                            "Sub A":
                                {
                                    "total": {"q1": 0,"q2": 0,"q3": 0,"q4": 0},
                                    "Profit": {"q1": 0,"q2": 0,"q3": 0,"q4": 0},
                                    "Loss": {"q1": 0,"q2": 0,"q3": 0,"q4": 0},
                                },
                            "Sub B":
                                {   "total": {"q1": 0,"q2": 0,"q3": 0,"q4": 0},
                                    "Profit": {"q1": 0,"q2": 0,"q3": 0,"q4": 0},
                                    "Loss": {"q1": 0,"q2": 0,"q3": 0,"q4": 0},
                                },
                        },
                    "A":
                        {
                            "overall":
                                {
                                    "total": {"q1": 0,"q2": 0,"q3": 0,"q4": 0},
                                    "Profit": {"q1": 0,"q2": 0,"q3": 0,"q4": 0},
                                    "Loss": {"q1": 0,"q2": 0,"q3": 0,"q4": 0},
                                },
                            "Sub A":
                                {
                                    "total": {"q1": 0,"q2": 0,"q3": 0,"q4": 0},
                                    "Profit": {"q1": 10,"q2": 8,"q3": 19,"q4": 7},
                                    "Loss": {"q1": 4,"q2": 2,"q3": 6,"q4": 10},
                                },
                            "Sub B":
                                {   "total": {"q1": 0,"q2": 0,"q3": 0,"q4": 0},
                                    "Profit": {"q1": 50,"q2": 70,"q3": 54,"q4": 77},
                                    "Loss": {"q1": 2,"q2": 8,"q3": 5,"q4": 40},
                                },
                        },
                    "B": 
                        {
                            "overall":
                                {
                                    "total": {"q1": 0,"q2": 0,"q3": 0,"q4": 0},
                                    "Profit": {"q1": 0,"q2": 0,"q3": 0,"q4": 0},
                                    "Loss": {"q1": 0,"q2": 0,"q3": 0,"q4": 0},
                                },
                            "Sub A":
                                {
                                    "total": {"q1": 0,"q2": 0,"q3": 0,"q4": 0},
                                    "Profit": {"q1": 75,"q2": 23,"q3": 25,"q4": 12},
                                    "Loss": {"q1": 64,"q2": 22,"q3": 12,"q4": 5},
                                },
                            "Sub B":
                                {   "total": {"q1": 0,"q2": 0,"q3": 0,"q4": 0},
                                    "Profit": {"q1": 65,"q2": 53,"q3": 3,"q4": 5},
                                    "Loss": {"q1": 10,"q2": 12,"q3": 1,"q4": 2},
                                },
                        }
                },
            },
        },

So far, I have the profit and loss data in the non overall dictionaries.
What I would like to do is have a function that populates the overall totals, profits and losses. For the sake of this, let's just say that profits and losses are aggregated so a profit of 1 and a loss of 1 makes a total of 2.
From looking at some similar questions and some thinking, i have the following:
def calculateOveralls(dictionary, query):
    for a in dictionary[query]: #A.B,C
        for b in dictionary[query][a]: #Sub A, Sub B, Sub C
            if b == "overall":
                pass
            else:
                for c in dictionary[query][a][b]:  # Profit/Loss
                    if c == "total":
                        pass
                    else:
                        for d in dictionary[query][a][b][c]:  # quarters
                            dictionary[query][a][b]["total"][d] = dictionary[query][a][b]["total"][d] + dictionary[query][a][b][c][d]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Many thanks!

Hello, to obtain a general algorithm to perform what you want to do, your best option is to do a recursive function. This function should iterate through your dictionary and once you find an "overall" key, you call the function itself to the sub-dictionary. If it's a different key, just do the processing you would do otherwise. If I can find some time today I would give it a try but you have at least the idea.

Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: a complete example of the sample data (i.e. do not simplify the code ... and provide non-zero values that need summing to help explain the process); a detailed English explanation of the logic you are trying to implement; and the expected output for that sample data. At the moment it is unclear which part of the dictionary you are trying to sum and the lack of usable data does not help.

@MT0 I hope this updated dict should be good. Would appreciate any help with this.

@Lrx I was thinking something along those lines too! Unfortunately trying to think through the logic has fried my brain!

You appear to have two levels of nested dictionaries within output["main"] and want to generate totals for each quarter and each permutation of level:
for main_key, main_value in output["main"].items():
    if main_key == "overall":
        continue
    for sub_key, sub_value in main_value.items():
        if sub_key == "overall":
            continue
        for q in ("q1", "q2", "q3", "q4"):
            profit = sub_value["Profit"][q]
            loss = sub_value["Loss"][q]
            sub_value["total"][q] = profit + loss
            output["main"]["overall"]["overall"]["Profit"][q] += profit
            output["main"]["overall"]["overall"]["Loss"][q] += loss
            output["main"]["overall"]["overall"]["total"][q] += profit + loss
            output["main"]["overall"][sub_key]["Profit"][q] += profit
            output["main"]["overall"][sub_key]["Loss"][q] += loss
            output["main"]["overall"][sub_key]["total"][q] += profit + loss
            output["main"][main_key]["overall"]["Profit"][q] += profit
            output["main"][main_key]["overall"]["Loss"][q] += loss
            output["main"][main_key]["overall"]["total"][q] += profit + loss

from pprint import pprint

pprint(output, width=100)

Which outputs:
{'main': {'A': {'Sub A': {'Loss': {'q1': 4, 'q2': 2, 'q3': 6, 'q4': 10},
                          'Profit': {'q1': 10, 'q2': 8, 'q3': 19, 'q4': 7},
                          'total': {'q1': 14, 'q2': 10, 'q3': 25, 'q4': 17}},
                'Sub B': {'Loss': {'q1': 2, 'q2': 8, 'q3': 5, 'q4': 40},
                          'Profit': {'q1': 50, 'q2': 70, 'q3': 54, 'q4': 77},
                          'total': {'q1': 52, 'q2': 78, 'q3': 59, 'q4': 117}},
                'overall': {'Loss': {'q1': 6, 'q2': 10, 'q3': 11, 'q4': 50},
                            'Profit': {'q1': 60, 'q2': 78, 'q3': 73, 'q4': 84},
                            'total': {'q1': 66, 'q2': 88, 'q3': 84, 'q4': 134}}},
          'B': {'Sub A': {'Loss': {'q1': 64, 'q2': 22, 'q3': 12, 'q4': 5},
                          'Profit': {'q1': 75, 'q2': 23, 'q3': 25, 'q4': 12},
                          'total': {'q1': 139, 'q2': 45, 'q3': 37, 'q4': 17}},
                'Sub B': {'Loss': {'q1': 10, 'q2': 12, 'q3': 1, 'q4': 2},
                          'Profit': {'q1': 65, 'q2': 53, 'q3': 3, 'q4': 5},
                          'total': {'q1': 75, 'q2': 65, 'q3': 4, 'q4': 7}},
                'overall': {'Loss': {'q1': 74, 'q2': 34, 'q3': 13, 'q4': 7},
                            'Profit': {'q1': 140, 'q2': 76, 'q3': 28, 'q4': 17},
                            'total': {'q1': 214, 'q2': 110, 'q3': 41, 'q4': 24}}},
          'overall': {'Sub A': {'Loss': {'q1': 68, 'q2': 24, 'q3': 18, 'q4': 15},
                                'Profit': {'q1': 85, 'q2': 31, 'q3': 44, 'q4': 19},
                                'total': {'q1': 153, 'q2': 55, 'q3': 62, 'q4': 34}},
                      'Sub B': {'Loss': {'q1': 12, 'q2': 20, 'q3': 6, 'q4': 42},
                                'Profit': {'q1': 115, 'q2': 123, 'q3': 57, 'q4': 82},
                                'total': {'q1': 127, 'q2': 143, 'q3': 63, 'q4': 124}},
                      'overall': {'Loss': {'q1': 80, 'q2': 44, 'q3': 24, 'q4': 57},
                                  'Profit': {'q1': 200, 'q2': 154, 'q3': 101, 'q4': 101},
                                  'total': {'q1': 280, 'q2': 198, 'q3': 125, 'q4': 158}}}}}

fiddle

I guess this is the function for the output you are trying to achieve:
def calculate_overalls(data, query):
    for sec in data[query]: # A, B etc
        all_profit = {"q1": 0, "q2": 0, "q3": 0, "q4": 0}
        all_loss = {"q1": 0, "q2": 0, "q3": 0, "q4": 0}
        all_total = {"q1": 0, "q2": 0, "q3": 0, "q4": 0}
        for sub_sec in data[query][sec]: # Sub A, Sub B etc
            if sub_sec == "overall":
                continue
            for q in ["q1", "q2", "q3", "q4"]:
                profit = data[query][sec][sub_sec]["Profit"][q]
                loss = data[query][sec][sub_sec]["Loss"][q]
                total = profit + loss
                # Add all to overall
                all_profit[q] += profit
                all_loss[q] += loss
                all_total[q] += total
        data[query][sec]["overall"]["Profit"] = all_profit
        data[query][sec]["overall"]["Loss"] = all_loss
        data[query][sec]["overall"]["total"] = all_total

output = {...}

calculate_overalls(output, "main")

print(output)

Or, comment the wrong estimate sections if you encounter unwanted results)

I'd recursively iterate until find dictionary which has "total" key, something like this:
def calculate_totals(summary_dict):

    for k, v in summary_dict.items():

        # may be redundant check if you have well defined structure
        if not isinstance(v, dict):
            continue

        if "total" in v.keys():
            for kk in v["total"].keys():
                v["total"][kk] = v["total"][kk] + v["Profit"][kk] + v["Loss"][kk]
        else:
            # recursively iterate until the dictionary has key "total"
            calculate_totals(v) 

calculate_totals(output)

You can retrieve "Profit" and "Loss" with get like this v["Profit"].get(kk, 0) + v["Loss"].get(kk, 0) if there may be cases with no 'q1', 'q2', etc. available keys.
